# Loading PFImageViews in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, imageview, scrollview, parse-platform

**I HAVE ANSWERED MY OWN QUESTION BELOW / FOUND A SOLUTION TO IT**

This is a DetailView so I have already passed the object from the first view. Plus I have to say that this is not the best way to show a load a "image gallery" which was what was intended in first place since it would have memory problems after adding many images. Anyways.. hope it helps someone in the future for anything they'd need or not.

How should I introduce the code to load the Next PFImageView in a ScrollView?

I'm trying to adapt this code setup in a PFImageView in a ScrollView:

```
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", i+1]];
```

Here is my code:

```
   PFImageView *lookView = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
   CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

   lookView.file = bellezaView.image_1,i+1;
```

But I get an Error expression "result unused"

Any help would really be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: None of this makes sense. Why would you want to do that? The imageNamed code is fine as-is and loads images from our app’s resources. If you are switching to loading files from the Parse servers instead clearly the code will look totally different, e.g. you would not use the same file names. lookView.file is a PFFile object so you’d have to create that first, using the correct URL and so on. Or maybe rephrase the question.

Comment: @n13 as you could see, I answered my own question and found the solution. I am not naming the images the same.. the files are image_1, image_2 and so on that is why the image_%d.. My answer is below and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the right way to go.. but this works.. hope it helps anyone trying to do the same:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
//Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[activityIndicator performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:60];


scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:20 animations:^{ScrollNext.alpha = 0.0;}];


NSInteger numberOfViews = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {


    PFImageView *lookView1 = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    lookView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lading.jpg"];
    lookView1.file = bellezaView.image_1;

    [scrollView addSubview:lookView1];
    [lookView1 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

    lookView1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    lookView1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);

            }
        }];

    PFImageView *lookView2 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
    lookView2.frame = CGRectMake(lookView1.frame.size.width*1, 0, 320, 500);

    lookView2.file = bellezaView.image_2;

    [scrollView addSubview:lookView2];
    [lookView2 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

    lookView2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    lookView2.frame = CGRectMake(lookView1.frame.size.width*1, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

            }
        }];

    PFImageView *lookView3 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
    lookView3.frame = CGRectMake(lookView1.frame.size.width*2, 0, 320, 500);

    lookView3.file = bellezaView.image_3;

    [scrollView addSubview:lookView3];
    [lookView3 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

    lookView3.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    lookView3.frame = CGRectMake(lookView1.frame.size.width*2, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

            }
        }];

        //Keep inserting views you stated before (in this case 5)

   }
}
```

Anyways.. hope it helps! :)